# Start activity in background

Tags: android, android-activity

I know you should use `services`, `backgroundtasks` and `AsynTask` for long running processes.  I've also seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16831229/how-to-start-an-activity-in-background-and-show-it-afterwards) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16057299/android-how-to-start-activity-in-background).
is there any way to start a activity in background and when process finishes, change the activity to current activity?
Suppose I have two activity A and B.
When user clicks on a view(a item in bottom navbar for example) on activity A, the desired action is to animate that view then start activity B.
But the problem is that there is a lag between animation terminate and starting of Activity B.
What I'm thinking of is to setup activity B while the view in activity A is animating.
As soon as animation terminates the activities swipe smoothly.
Is there a possible solution for this?

Comment: What is causing the lag?

Comment: @Tim Castelijns probably the setting ups in the activity (like inflating view, etc), gets some time. maybe we ca prepare activity while the view is animating.